# Terminal suspend on Ubuntu 8.04

Tags: command-line, suspend

I'm trying to put my old laptop into suspend mode through the terminal.
Typing `rtcwake -m disk -s 10` works in newer versions but in 8.04 I get:

```
error /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/device/power/wakeup: No such file or directory"
rtcwake: /dev/rtc0 not enabled for wakeup events.
```

I have tried googling this but all I get is people asking this very question with no answers.

How can I suspend the computer for a pre-determined amount of time from the terminal, in older Ubuntu versions?

Comment: Offbeat question.. is any specific reason for using Ubuntu 8.04?

Comment: my computer is 12 years old and crashes when i try to install newer versions.

Comment: 8.04 is no longer supported on desktops.  You need to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Sleep: `pmi action suspend`

Hibernate: `pmi action hibernate`

Sleep after 40 minutes: `echo 'pmi action suspend' | at now + 40 minutes`

You can also use the gnome commands:

```
gnome-power-cmd suspend
gnome-power-cmd hibernate
```

Comment: how do i, for instance, make it suspend for ten minutes and then wake up?

Comment: I can't find any manual page for pmi. Could you do a `man pmi` and see if 8.04 has a man page and if so if it has options?

Comment: 'man pmi' gives me nothing but 'info man' gives me a description, but in it I see nothing in the options letting me determine the amount of time.

Comment: @Rinzwind - welcome to the 20K+ club!

Comment: thanks fossfreedom ! and @hermann then you can forget about it on 8.04 ... sorry :(